# Contact provider for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, contacts

How can I make an app for Windows Phone that provides contacts to the people hub but these contacts must not sync with Whatsapp.

I know this is possible because contacts with phone numbers from Facebook aren't synced with Whatsapp.

In what field of a contact should the phone number be stored so that WhatsApp can't read it.

What are the APIs and if there is an app like that existing in the store, what is it?
PS. I am developing for WP8.1 or WM10.

Comment: You will have to store those contacts in you app locally, so that other apps cant access the contacts.

Comment: Yeah, but the point is to make the contact available in the hub but not for WhatsApp. Facebook contact sync does this